# I need to extract first char from each word and use a "_"in between after using split()

Tags: java, string, char

Like in the topic. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong honestly. 
After charAt it's obviously a char, but I need to get that char from second word... and add a '_' inbetween the two. Help anyone?

```
    String[] splited = im_naz.split(" ");
    char s;
    String str;

    c1 = splited[0].charAt(0);
    c2 = splited[1].charAt(0);
    str = c1 + '_' + c2;
```

I know I'm doing this wrong, but I honestly have no idea how to do this...

Comment: What is your expected input?

Comment: Input and expected output would help, I don't really understand the logic here.

Comment: Use two " instead of the '

Comment: Please indicate what the input String is and what output you expect. Note - your c1/c2 vars are 'char' type so the '+' operator is mathematical addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got `char + char + char`. Now, the compiler is going to work out that when you add three `char` values together, they will create an `int`. So you're effectively trying to say:

```
String value = 5; // Or some other integer. 5 is just an example.
```

This won't compile because you're trying to assign an `int` to a `String`. To remedy this, you need to make sure that your values are *promoted* to a `String`. Doing that is easy. Change `'_'` for `"_"`. Overall, your statement will now be:

```
str = c1 + "_" + c2;
```

**Extra Reading**

- You need to read about [Java Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).
- You should also look into [Arithmetic Promotion](http://www.codemiles.com/java/arithmetic-promotion-t3487.html).

Comment: So this means now I will have letter_letter right...?  It's something as stupid as that. uh. Thank you.

Comment: Yes you will! But the important principle here is *arithmetic promotion*. `char + char` will be *promoted* to an `int`, which isn't implicitly compatible with `String`. By changing the `'` to an `"`, you've forced the compiler to promote it to a `String`, which is compatible!

Answer (score 0):

On the last line, just use double quotation marks as opposed to single ones and the outcome should be what you want.

str = c1 + "_"+ c2;